# SQL ID Problem with order by ID DESC

Tags: mysql, sql

i using in my application IDs with 5 Digits (11000, 11001...), but now i wont to use 6 Digits (110000, 110001...)

So the Problem is the ordering! 11010 is bigger then 110000 what can i do?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are storing your IDs as strings (varchar) rather than as a numeric type. Can you not use a numeric type?

If not then is it an option to update all existing IDs and prefix with a zero, e.g. "11010" becomes "011010"?

Answer (score 0):

I think your id column is varchar it schould be int

but maybe did can help you

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209632

to order string as numeric